# efficient way to do stratified sampling in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Google Big Query table called **TableA** that has ~3M records. There is a column called **DimA**  (Dimension A) that has 20 values - 1 to 20. The counts by each value of **DimA** is shown in the summary table below in the **Total** column. I did some analysis and determined how much random sample I should draw from each value of **DimA** and it is shown in the column **Sample**. The % of sample drawn by each value of **DimA** is shown in column **DimA_value_perc**. I know how to do sample via brute force using the code below the table. However, this code is not scalable as the number of values of DimA grows and in case there are additional dimensions. Is there a more efficient way to do the stratified sampling? Thanks.

| DimA | Total | Sample | DimA_value_perc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 115,623 | 3,077 | 3% |
| 2 | 108,203 | 3,943 | 4% |
| 3 | 153,477 | 6,802 | 4% |
| 4 | 232,252 | 12,426 | 5% |
| 5 | 223,004 | 14,052 | 6% |
| 6 | 242,386 | 17,589 | 7% |
| 7 | 121,519 | 9,783 | 8% |
| 8 | 371,342 | 34,026 | 9% |
| 9 | 147,683 | 15,400 | 10% |
| 10 | 281,101 | 32,775 | 12% |
| 11 | 93,380 | 12,075 | 13% |
| 12 | 181,293 | 25,675 | 14% |
| 13 | 122,206 | 19,344 | 16% |
| 14 | 140,559 | 25,141 | 18% |
| 15 | 95,576 | 19,498 | 20% |
| 16 | 94,319 | 21,969 | 23% |
| 17 | 108,282 | 30,054 | 28% |
| 18 | 94,920 | 33,228 | 35% |
| 19 | 82,764 | 39,700 | 48% |
| 20 | 28,417 | 23,442 | 82% |
| Grand Total | 3,038,306 | 400,000 |  |

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
where DimA = 1
order by rand()
limit  3077 

union all

SELECT *
FROM tableA
where DimA = 2
order by rand()
limit   3943 

etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with samples as (
  select 1 DimA, 115623 Total, 3077 Sample, 3 DimA_value_perc union all
  select 2, 108203, 3943, 4 union all
  select 3, 153477, 6802, 4 union all
  select 4, 232252, 12426, 5 union all
  select 5, 223004, 14052, 6 union all
  select 6, 242386, 17589, 7 union all
  select 7, 121519, 9783, 8 union all
  select 8, 371342, 34026, 9 union all
  select 9, 147683, 15400, 10 union all
  select 10, 281101, 32775, 12 union all
  select 11, 93380, 12075, 13 union all
  select 12, 181293, 25675, 14 union all
  select 13, 122206, 19344, 16 union all
  select 14, 140559, 25141, 18 union all
  select 15, 95576, 19498, 20 union all
  select 16, 94319, 21969, 23 union all
  select 17, 108282, 30054, 28 union all
  select 18, 94920, 33228, 35 union all
  select 19, 82764, 39700, 48 union all
  select 20, 28417, 23442, 82 
)
select a.* except(pos) from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by DimA order by rand()) pos
  from tableA
) a
join samples 
using(DimA)
where pos <= Sample
```